# "Оставить" или "дать" номер телефона?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Сегодня в своём учебном заведении я попросил диспетчера "оставить мне номер телефона" одного преподавателя. Меня поправили: *Как-то не по-русски, следовало спросить так: "Дайте, пожалуйста, номер телефона".*

Выражение "оставить номер телефона" предполагает инициативу от того, кто должен оставить? Этот человек сам должен предложить и записать свой номер на клочке бумаги, дать визитку?

Answer (score 2):

Так **можно** попросить номер телефона у *человека, который собрался уходить*, например, у посетителя. Видимо, диспетчера удивило, что его "выпроваживают".

Comment: А если это, например, знакомство с девушкой на улице. Эта территория никому не принадлежит, чтобы кого-то выпроваживать