# Можно ли сказать, что человек "оставляет свой номер телефона"?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Можно ли, пытаясь взять у человека номер телефона, сказать: "Вы не могли бы оставить свой номер телефона" вместо "дать номер"? Можно ли так же выразиться по отношению к адресу: оставить адрес?

Comment: Такой вопрос уже был: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/457633 Не вы ли его задавали (там тоже Владимир)?

Comment: Да, это был я. Здесь речь идёт и об адресе.

Comment: С адресом то же самое.

Comment: oleedd, Если дать номер, то это  все равно что совсем отдать. в вечное пользование.  А оставляют номер только на время – для решения конкретного вопроса. Потом его рекомендуется забыть :)

Comment: @Sharon *Если дать номер, то это все равно что совсем отдать* — нет, так люди не говорят. Это как "дай ссылку", человек её копирует, она у него при этом не исчезает, как и номер. Подумайте, когда вы скажете "дай ключи", а когда — "оставь ключи". *А оставляют номер только на время* — получается, что его потом заберут.

Comment: oleedd, это же подтекст, тонкая психология...  Если вы даете кому-то телефон, то это намек на то, что вы не против телефонного общения с этим лицом.  А если вы телефон всего лишь оставляете, то тем самым намекаете на его разовое использование :)

Comment: @Sharon Теперь вы чётко выразились, без логических нестыковок. В вопросе речь идёт только о "не могли бы оставить/дать".

Answer (score 2):

*Оставить свой номер телефона, оставить свой адрес* — да, так можно говорить.
Такое значение глагола [оставить](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&ro=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C) есть в толковом словаре:
**2.** Передать кому-либо для кого-либо при уходе, отъезде и т. п.; отложить, сохранить для кого-либо, чего-либо. *Оставь мне ключи. Оставил матери записку. Оставил для тебя последний номер журнала. Оставь молока кошке. Оставить путёвки для ветеранов. Оставить конфеты к чаю. Оставить стирку на вечер. **Оставь свой адрес*** (сообщи). *Оставь что-либо на память* (подарить). *Оставь свои сомненья при себе* (не высказывай вслух).

― Да, синьор уезжает сегодня поутру, он позвонит вам, если это так срочно, через полчаса, потрудитесь **оставить свой номер**. [Б. Л. Пастернак. Апеллесова черта (1915)]

С объектива снимают чёрный колпачок ― и готово, ты уже запечатлен. Карточки завтра, можно **оставить адрес** ― пришлют. [Василий Аксенов. Пора, мой друг, пора (1963)]

Общение с кем-то (на улице, в помещении, по телефону), конечно же, не может быть бесконечным. Но если вы в начале или в середине разговора вместо глагола "дать" используете "оставить", то у собеседника может возникнуть ощущение, что вы хотите побыстрее закончить этот разговор.