# Дефис в слове «стрип-клуб»

Tags: слитно-дефис, дефис

Стоит ли ставить дефис в слове «стрип-клуб»? При сокращении части сложного слова дефис сохраняется?

Comment: Владимир, почему Вы совсем перестали принимать ответы? Даже стрелочку не нажимаете. Неужели, например, [этот ответ](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/467438/Можно-ли-сказать-что-человек-оставляет-свой-номер-телефона/467441#467441) не был полезен?

Comment: Да, обленился, Вы правы — исправлюсь!

Comment: Наверстывайте! :) Думаю, спустя время отвечающим приятно будет увидеть зелененькие десятки и пятнашки.

Comment: Владимир, у Вас остались сомнения по поводу моих ответов?

Comment: Добавлю немного статистики. Владимир зада 64 вопроса, но принял только 8, то есть один вопрос из каждых восьми.  Да и комментирует ответы он тоже не очень охотно, так что  отвечающие чаще  разговаривают между собой.

Comment: Нет, нет, я поставил стрелочку, а только что, поняв, что других ответов более не предвидится, и галочку.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Да, дефис нужен.

> [**стрип-…**](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BF&all=x) – *первая часть сложных слов, пишется через дефис.*

стрип-бар
стрип-балет
стрип-заведение
стрип-танцовщица (источник: Грамота.ру)

[**Kaк пишeтcя cлoвo "cтpип-клyб"?**](https://orf.textologia.ru/definit/strip-klub/?q=532&n=138829) (источник: TextoLogia.ru)

> Пpaвильнoe нaпиcaниe: cтpип-клyб

От себя добавлю. Мы говорим *стриптиз-клуб* и пишем через дефис, так же как и, например, *бизнес-центр*. Сокращение на написание не влияет. Но если бы мы говорили *стриптизный* или *стриптизёрный клуб*, то, скорее всего, писали бы слитно, по аналогии со *спортплощадкой, гендиректором*.